# How to remove side bar in my html page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to design an html for this I have downloaded sb-admin2 bootstrap template.

Here I want to remove left sidebar how would I do that. 
then navbar goes upwards, I need to make it down

[image]

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v7f0ma8f/3/

```
<br><br><br>
                        <nav class="navbar" style=" border-color:blue;width:500px;">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="#">New Project</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pyramid Opportunities</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                         <br><br><br>

                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                         <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SMS</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">EMAIL</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SMS/EMAIL</a></li>                                      

                                    </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                             <div class="form-body">  <!-- flot-chart previus class name -->

                            <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">HI.</div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Hello.</div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Bye.</div>

                                    </div>
                         </div>
                         <!-- /.form-body -->
                         </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->       
                        </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->   
                    </div>
```

Comment: Your `#page-wrapper` element has `margin: 0 0 0 250px;`. You need to set `margin: 0 0 0 0;` or just `margin-left: 0;` in your css to remove empty space on the left.

Comment: first never use <br> for layout structure. I wan't to help you, but please clarify your question better.  What you want to move and where

Comment: Nav bar and the panel should have some space like nav bar attached to too much top nad between nav bar and panel i need some space

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
#page-wrapper {
    margin: 0 ;
}
```

Update this class with margin 0 in all devices where you don't want leftbar.

Comment: i have done this works fine before this answer. can you have in my below fiddle i have placed border for nav bar can you suggest how to do  square box type nav bar

Comment: I didn't get your question. Can you please elaborate your phrase "how to do square box type nav bar " with some more details or a desired image would work for me to understand.

Thanks

Comment: i have put one image please see

Comment: Are you looking for something like this

Updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v7f0ma8f/12/